# Fast hamming distance between 2 bitset

Tags: c++

I'm writing a software that heavily relies on (1) accessing single bit and (2) Hamming distance computations between 2 bitset A and B (ie. the numbers of bits that differ between A and B). The bitsets are quite big, between 10K and 1M bits and i have a bunch of them. Since it is impossible to know the bitset sizes at compilation time, i'm using `vector < bool >` , but i plan to migrate to `boost::dynamic_bitset` soon.

Hereafter are my questions:

(1) Any ideas about which implementations have the fastest single bit access time?

(2) To compute Hamming distance, the naive approach is to loop over the single bits and to count differences between the 2 bitsets. But, my feeling is that it might be much faster to loop over bytes instead of bits, perform R = byteA XOR byteB, and look in a table with 255 entries what "local" distance is associated with R. Another solutions would be store a 255 x 255 matrix and access directly without operation to the distance between byteA and byteB. So my question: Any idea how to implement that from `std::vector < bool >` or boost::dynamic_bitset? In other words, do you know if there is a way to get access to the bytes array or i have to recode everything from scratch?

Comment: Have you tried using the dynamic_bitset's `operator^` and `count()` methods, and profiling that to see if performance is adequate? It may be the implementation is already good enough for you.

Comment: Given the various answers, i've just done some basic testings using boost::dynamic_bitset & vector < bool > with optimization flag -O2. Access times between both implementations are roughly the same (3% of difference). More importantly, if you use operator^ and count() for hamming distance, you divide your running time by 10 compare to the naive approach!!! Waou, thanks a lot!

Comment: @koskos Please, post benchmarking code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) Probably `vector<char>` (or even `vector<int>`), but that wastes at least 7/8 space on typical hardware. You don't need to unpack the bits if you use a byte or more to store them. Which of `vector<bool>` or `dynamic_bitset` is faster, I don't know. That might depend on the C++ implementation.

(2) `boost::dynamic_bitset` has `operator^` and a `count` member, which together can be used to compute the Hamming distance in a probably fast, though memory-wasting way. You can also get to the underlying buffer with [`to_block_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#to_block_range); to use that, you need to implement a Hamming distance calculator as an `OutputIterator`.

Answer (score 2):

If you do code from scratch, you can probably do even better than a byte at a time: take a word at a time from each bitset. The cost of XOR should be very low, then use either an implementation-specific builtin `popcount`, or else the fastest bit-twiddling popcount you can find (which may or may not involve a 256-entry lookup).

[Edit: looks as if this could apply to `boost::dynamic_bitset::to_block_range`, with the `Block` chosen as either `int` or `long`. It's a shame that it writes to an OutputIterator rather than giving you an InputIterator -- I can't immediately see how to use it to iterate over two bitsets together, except by using an extra thread or else copying one of the bitsets out to an `int` array first. Either way you'll take some copy overhead that could have been avoided if it had left the program control to you. The thread is pretty complicated for this task, and of course has its own overheads, and copying out the data probably isn't any better than using `operator^` and `count()`.]

Answer (score 0):

I know this will get downvoted for heresy, but here it is: you can get a pointer to the  actual data from a vector using &vector[0]; (for vector ymmv). Then, you can iterate over it using c-style functions; meaning, cast your pointer to an int pointer or something big like that, perform your hamming arithmetic as above, and move the pointer one word-length at a time. This would only work because you know that the bits are packed together continuously, and would be vulnerable (for example, if the vector is modified, it could move memory locations).

Comment: Not so much heresy, as the fact that `vector<bool>` isn't a container, and its `operator[]` doesn't return a reference to the data buffer. It's close-packed to save memory, but the cost of that is that individual bits don't have addresses in C++. So the "YMMV" is quite an important caveat.

Comment: Doh. Now I see. Not clever enough. Sounds like vector<bool> is something to be avoided anyway: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=98